# Regex to match certain conditions

Tags: ruby, regex

Basically I want a regex to match this conditions

1. **First 8 characters should be within [a-zA-Z]**
2. *Followed by any number of digits*
3. ***Followed by any word character but not immediately folowed by "or" or "and"***

I current have this regex:

```
^(?i:([a-z]{1,8})(\d+)((?!or|and).)+)$
```

this works fine for the following example:

- **ABCDEFGH***1****ZZZ***
- **GFEDCBAH***99****ZZZ99***

but NOT with this one because I think if satisfy "OR" in the "FORALL":

- **WOLRDWAR***2****FORALL***

Expected output:

```
AAAAAAAA100NANDROID - should match
AAAAAAAA100ANDROID - should not match
AAAAAAAA100OR - should not match
AAAAAAAA100AND - should not match
```

Basically I don't want the FOR match the OR, any solution for my problem? btw, this is for Ruby

Comment: Define "followed by". Do you mean "end with"? Delimited by whitespace? Other?

Comment: i mean exactly likethat, I edited to make it clearer, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with @anubhava regex and the others like it, is that
its too liberal using `.*` after the assertion.

That means it can split the expression *before* the assertion then
pick it up on the other side.

For example    `^(?i:([a-z]{8})(\d+)((?!or|and).*))$` easily matches `AAAAAAAA100AND`

This is a rare case that causes the engine to backtrack a digit, to satisfy the assertion.
Usually, if `.*` were not used, it would be unnecessary to be concerned.

This can be fixed by injecting a `\d*` construct in the assertion.
Be aware that assertions are stand alone, they will match first then check if it should fail second. But this does not prevent the engine from backtracking if it can.

`^(?i:([a-z]{8})(\d+)((?!\d*(?:or|and)).*))$`

Expanded:

```
 ^ 
 (?i:
      ( [a-z]{8} )                  # (1)
      ( \d+ )                       # (2)

      (                             # (3 start)
           (?!
                \d* 
                (?: or | and )
           )
           .* 
      )                             # (3 end)
 )
 $
```

Comment: Indeed you are correct, would your edit the same with my solution to that problem?  `^(?i:([a-z]{8})(\d+)((?!(?:or|and))\D.*))$`

Comment: Not sure. It looks ok but I think my way is better if you expect there to be optional words at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak your regex as:

```
/^(?i:([a-z]{8})(\d+)((?!or|and).*))$/
```

[RegEx Demo](http://rubular.com/r/WGZ47B9I5o)

Comment: Basically I want WORLDWAR2**FOR**ALL to be match but not WORLDWAR2**OR**ALL

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this (I am using a positive look-behind `(?<=\d)` so that we only exclude `or` or `and` that are preceded by a digit):

```
^(?i:([a-z]{1,8})(\d+)((?!(?<=\d)(?:or|and)).)+)$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bJ5bG7/1)

Answer (score 1):

anubhava's answer seems to match the correct values, but all of the previous answers seem to include one or more capture groups, which I didn't see requested in your original post. Here's another possible solution that will match the entire string without groups:

```
^(?i:[a-z]{8}\d+(?!or|and).*)$
```

[Rubular Demo](http://rubular.com/r/taKH5gg8Dt)